# method does not override a method from a supertype

Tags: java

I facing an weird issue.
I have extended abstract class `ServletOutputStream` and implemented required abstract methods. But still it’s saying

> method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Please help

**Code :**

```
class TestOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {

        }
        @Override
        public  void setWriteListener(WriteListener writeListener){

        }   
        @Override
        public  boolean isReady(){
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps one of those methods for which you have provided an @override annotation is not, in fact, present in a superclass. Like maybe `isReady()`.

Comment: I don't think you need an `@Override` annotation. What happens if you remove them?

Comment: which Java EE version are you using?

Comment: you simply don't compile your class against a servlet 3.1 jar which defines methods ServletOutputStream.isReady and setWriteListener

Comment: While not strictly necessary, the `@Override` annotation is useful. Here it alerts OP that there is some problem. It's likely a problem in their environment--using an unexpected version of Java EE, it would seem--but still a useful indication that there is a problem. If one removes the `@Override` then one has code that compiles and runs but perhaps does not behave as expected. Silent failures are worse than "weird" IDE messages.

Answer (score 4):

You have provided the @Override annotation for your `isReady()` method, however in Java EE 6 or earlier there is no such method in any superclass.

Comment: [Really?](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html#isReady--)

Comment: This is not correct. ServletOutputStream does have a method isReady(). See the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html

Comment: Are you using java 7 EE? It's not in Java 6 EE or earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you've accidentely used wrong javaee api version? 6th and 5th [doesn't have](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html) some of the methods.